# PHP variables inside a variable

Tags: php

I have an error somewhere in this line of code, if I take `"by"` off the line it works fine.

```
$msg = 'An Order has just been submitted on CID, Number' . $_POST['orderNumber']'by' .$name;
```

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Missed the dot. it's `$_POST['orderNumber'] .'by '. $name;`

Comment: As an aside - as this is an output message, it probably doesn't need to be a string literal (which is what apostrophes denote) - and it's best not to directly output something from a $_POST either. It would be better to sanitise/encode your strings and then assign the output message thus `$msg = "An Order has just been submitted on CID, Number {$orderNumber} by {$name}";` - means you'd avoid that missing concatentor issue as well ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would advise you to utilize one of PHPs core language features. PHP supports variable interpolation in *double quoted strings*. That's much simpler than the cumbersome string concatenation:

```
$msg = "An Order has just been submitted on CID, Number $_POST[orderNumber] by $name";
```

Note that as special exception no array key quotes are to be used there for simple arrays. (Other examples see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php)

Also note that you should actually escape (see `htmlspecialchars`) incoming $_POST or $_GET variables, if they are to be used for output again.

Comment: Why would you advise this mario? Why would you argue that this is better than string concatenation?

Comment: @stereofrog Yah, silently added a note about that too. (Though string might go elsewhere in the example..?)

Comment: @NikiC: Well, OP stumbled upon the concat syntax. I would guess he has no editor with syntax highlighting (= problem 2). Otherwise I find vars in dquotes more readable (if editor supported). And generally I do not buy into the single quotes microoptimization thing.

Comment: I don't by the optimization thing either, but I would argue that advising newbies to use the simple string interpolation syntax may have bad effects on their future coding.

Comment: @NikiC Hmm, eventually. I've seen some awful misuse too, but in this case it's clearly the more readable approach. Sadly we don't seem to have a good reference question with pros/cons advise (other than the irrelevant benchmarking issue). And the manual is no good guide on that either.

Comment: @mario My problem with the syntax is that newbies often follow from it: "Ah, I don't need to put quotes around the array index". I don't really have a problem with interpolation per se, but I would advise to use the "... {$_POST['orderNumber']} ..." syntax.

Comment: @NikiC I tried to be subtle with "as special exception", and would have left the explaining to /book.strings.php. However no amount of advising or good answers will cease that particular noob problem. It's mostly outdated PHP3 tutorials which spread the unquoted strings problem I'd say. (And lack of error_reporting settings or zero willingness to google the messages.) -- Just from the writing I would however presume OP is not in danger here.

Comment: It's not really a string "optimisation" thing - PHP sort of supports 2 different kinds of string; generally I'd use string literals for things like array keys or constants, define('CONST', 7), where the contents of the string need to be taken, erm, literally :) For output strings I'd use double quotes which allows you to do things like, echo "Hello {$sPlanetOfChoice}!\n";

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you never concatenate `$_POST['orderNumber']` and `'by'` properly (via the `.` operator).

```
$msg = 'An Order has just been submitted on CID, Number ' . $_POST['orderNumber'] . ' by ' . $name; // Notice the . (and a few spaces)
```

Comment: You are a 10.4k rep user. Please lead by good example and close questions like this as too localized. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you forgot to concatenate 'by'. Just add the concatenation . infront of 'by'

Answer (score 2):

You for got the `.`

```
$_POST['orderNumber'] . 'by'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$msg = 'An Order has just been submitted on CID, Number'.$_POST['orderNumber'].'by'.$name;
```